# Angular Post cant set observe to response

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having problems getting a http post to work with the **observe** set to **response** as shown below.
This is very confusing, as all I wanted was more details responses with the status code, so I can decide what to do base on status codes.

I am importing the following parts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
```

This is the method that fails

```
getPage(pageRequest: UsersPageRequest): Observable<UsersPageResponse[]> {
    
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'ApiKey': 'something', 
        'UserToken': this.localStorageService.getUserToken()
    })
    let options = { 
        headers: headers, 
        observe: "response"
    };
    return this.http.post<UsersPageResponse[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users/page', pageRequest, options);
}
```

How can I get this to work?, as at the moment it seems very fragile!

[image]

---- Update ----

I later tried what @Panagiotis mentioned but still got it erroring.

[image]

I realised that I had already implemented an error interceptor that handles this for me which I will post below.

Comment: I suggest using `const` instead of `let`, you are initializing `headers` and `options` once, why do you need to be declared with `let`?

Comment: The second error just means you need to change the return type of the calling function. You're very close now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thrown error is

> Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.  Type 'string' is not
> assignable to type '"events"'. Types of property 'observe' are
> incompatible.  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"response"'.
> Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.  Type 'string' is not
> assignable to type '"body" | undefined'.

This is a common mind blowing issue

The following will not work

```
let options = { 
        headers: headers, 
        observe: "response"
    };
    return this.http.post<UsersPageResponse[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users/page', pageRequest, options);
```

**But the following** **will work**

```
return this.http.post<UsersPageResponse[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users/page', pageRequest, { headers: headers,  observe: "response" });
```

In the first case, TypeScript infers the type of options to be `{observe: string}`. The type is too wide to pass to `HttpClient.post` which is expecting the type of observe to be one of the specific strings `'body' | 'events' | 'response'`. HttpClient is typed explicitly this way so that the compiler can report the correct return type based on the options you provided.

This issue is also mentioned in [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response)

**The following will also work** as the keyword `as const` helps the type to not get wider during type inference.

```
let options = { 
            headers: headers, 
            observe: "response" as const  <----
        };
        return this.http.post<UsersPageResponse[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users/page', pageRequest, options);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this I will give this a go this evening and if all good will mark as the answer, much appreciated

Comment: This didn't work for me but will thumbs up for trying to help me, thanks, I tried both approaches, I realised later that I implemented an error interceptor that handles this anyway and actually work too. Ill add the details to my original to prove it

Comment: Sounds like the second error was the return type changes, I didnt end up doing this as thought it made more sense to just use the Error Interceptor as I documents as the other answer, cheers

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was not to follow this any more, as it seemed futile to get working, I had actually already implemented an error interceptor as follows which then provided a central place to handle exceptions.

```
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, retry } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req)
            .pipe(
                retry(1), 
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    let errorMessage = '';
                    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                        // client-side error
                        errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
                    } else {
                        // server-side error
                        errorMessage = `Error Status: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
                    }
                    console.log(errorMessage);
                    if(error.status == 401) {
                        // unauthorised redirect to the route you want
                        this.router.navigate(['',])
                    }
                    return throwError(errorMessage);
                })
            );
    }

}
```

This provider was then added to the **app.module.ts** file and I can get the status codes

```
providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
    useClass: ErrorInterceptor, 
    multi: true
  }],
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you too read a bit more on how the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) works.

Basically you have 15 possible combinations of headers, responseType and other elements that identify each possible http post overload.

You need to find the appropriate combination that matches the type of request that you want to perform.

I would say what you are missing is the `responseType: 'json'` for it to be valid. However without knowing what you expect to receive I'm not 100% certain.