# Cant set option observe:'responce' for httpClient

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient

I am trying to create a service for downloading blob files, but i need headers of responce. So i need to set `observe` option to `responce`. When i'am trying to do it like in angular docs:

```
return this.http
      .post(urlCompleted, body, {
        headers,
        observe: 'responce',
        responseType: 'blob',
      })
```

i get an error:

```
The last overload gave the following error.
  Type '"responce"' is not assignable to type '"body" | undefined'.
    Type '"blob"' is not assignable to type '"json" | undefined'.
```

here [Angular Post cant set observe to response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69123639/angular-post-cant-set-observe-to-response) people sugests to set options inline, but as you see its doesent working.

I also tried to do it like this:

```
return this.http
  .post(urlCompleted, body, {
    headers,
    observe: 'responce' as 'body',
    responseType: 'blob',
  })
```

and yeah, typescript is happy now, but i get another error in browser: `ERROR Error: Unreachable: unhandled observe type responce}`

Soo, what im doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps `responce` should be spelled `response`?

Comment: @R.Richards, I am not at the computer already, and tomorrow will check it and if you are right I will feel myself so stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple, i needed to use "response" not "responce". Time to study grammar.

Thanks to @R.Richards from comments.